# Valor de data vindo de função JsonResult 18/11/2018 00:00:00 javascript recebe "/Date(1542506400000)/"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tendo problema com o recebimento de uma função `JsonResult` que me retorna uma determinada data e esta data não estou conseguindo passar para o campo Data de minha tela por motivos de vir um valor diferente da formatação do campo.

A função C# `JsonResult` passa o seguinte valor: 18/11/2018 00:00:00

> Minha função Javascript recebe "/Date(1542506400000)/"

Como faço para o campo

```
document.getElementById("AnuncioDataFim").value = n.AnuncioDataFim;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você teria que ver se consegue configurar como as datas são serializadas no C#, mas você pode converter o valor recebido em JS pois o inteiro que está dentro de `Date` é a quantidade de milisegundos desde de `01/01/1970 00:00:00 UTC`.

Utilizando uma regex você poderia pegar este número e usar no construtor do [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) e depois formatar a data como bem entender.

Exemplo:

```js
function parseDate(dateString) {
  let result = /Date\((\d+)\)/.exec(dateString)
  
  // Se não seguir o padrão da Regex retorna null
  if (!result) {
    return null;
  }
  
  let miliseconds = parseInt(result[1], 10);
  let date = new Date(miliseconds);
  
  return `${date.getDate()}/${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getFullYear()}`;
}

// 18/11/2018
let date_1 = "/Date(1542506400000)/";  // 
console.log(date_1 + " == " + parseDate(date_1));

// 30/10/2018
let date_2 = "/Date(1540899418346)/"
console.log(date_2 + " == " + parseDate(date_2));
```